# Simple Future vs Future Perfect

Tags: tenses, future, future-perfect

Mother: Have you completed your homework?
1. Son: I will complete my homework before 6 P.M.
2. Son: I will have completed my homework before 6 P.M.

Are both sentences 1 and 2 correct?
Which one is more appropriate, and what's the difference in meaning both conveys?

Comment: Both sentences are equally grammatical. Both sentences are also equally not English in that nobody, ever, talks like that. Least of all a son to his mother.

Answer (score 0):

The future perfect expresses completed action in future time.  The future simply expresses action in future time.  Because the verb 'complete' was used in the question, the distinction is muddied.  Let's try another verb, 'sharpen'.  Observe the contrast between:

- I will sharpen the blade Tuesday at 9:00 am.
- I will have sharpened the blade by Tuesday at 9:00 am.

Comment: Could you explain why "complete" muddies the distinction?